# Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to minimize a window?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I'm looking at the window manager keyboard settings but I don't see it. There are shortcuts for maximize, hide, move, and so forth, so I'd think I was on the right page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awww, fer crying out loud. I found it. "Minimize" has been renamed "Hide". Why did they do that?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>⇩</kbd> pressed once will exit the maximized mode, then on the second press - minimize it

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to assign a single key. Every version of Linux I've ever used, I was able to assign the super key to minimize the window and the right menu key to send it to the back. This is the first version of Linux where I couldn't do that.

Comment: Well, at this moment all I could think of is binding a single key to `xdotool key Ctrl+Super+Down` command, but perhaps other people will come up with other , better solutions

Comment: I'm ok with that.

Comment: Very cool, especially `Ctrl+Super+Left` and `Right`. The minimise on down arrow twice doesn't work for me though. Maybe because I installed Ubuntu and then changed the DE to Gnome?

Answer (score 0):

Use the steps below to minimize the active window with <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Right Super</kbd>

1. Install the package `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Install the package `xbindkeys`
3. Edit your `xbindkeys` configuration, e.g.:

   ```
   nano ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

   and add one of the configurations below

   for <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>

   ```
   "xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize"
       Control_R
   ```

   or for <kbd>Right Super</kbd>

   ```
   "xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize"
       Super_R
   ```
4. Kill all `kbindkeys` processes*

   ```
   killall xbindkeys
   ```
5. Restart `xbindkeys` with your configuration, eg:

   ```
   xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

---

For an other key use

```
xbindkeys --key
```

to find the correct name

*Example for* <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>

```
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x14 + c:37
    Control+Mod2 + Control_L
```

therefore use `Control_L`

* If this was not the first time you've configured `xbindkeys`, you can type `killall -HUP xbindkeys` instead and skip step 5.

Comment: *Sigh*. Thanks. I'll try it. This sort of stuff is why Linux still isn't ready for the desktop.